# first word not visible when compiling citation in overleaf

Tags: latex, overleaf

im citing a website link in overleaf. however full name is not visible in compiling. instead of getting `(Department of Agriculture and Farmers Welfare, 2022)` I'm getting `(of Agriculture and Farmers Welfare, 2022)`.

```
citation: @misc{rainfed,
    author = {Department of Agriculture and Farmers Welfare},
    title = {rainfed},
    year = {2022},
    month = {November 16},
    url = {https://agricoop.gov.in/en/RainfedDiv}
}
```

bibliography:   `\bibliography{agusample}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Department" is parsed as the author's first name, and "of Agriculture and Farmers Welfare" as the last name.

Add an additional pair of braces, like so:

```
author = {{Department of Agriculture and Farmers Welfare}},
```